# How to optimize a website design?

Tags: website-design, interface-design, design-principles

If you have a working website, is there a way to tell if parts of it are bad or good?

For example, I have created a cryptocurrency platform which I develop as a hobby project whenever I have spare time.

I would like to know if my design is user-friendly or could be improved, is there any online tools or similar that can tell me if parts or even whole pages are horribly designed?

Do I need to hire people to give me feedback, or what is the go-to source to solve stuff like that?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you should do is figure out exactly what you're wanting to improve. Pleasantness? Brand persona? UX? Accessibility (for what type of person/device?)? Making money? Time spent on the website? SEO? I could go on. There's very many focuses of websites that could be improved and it's your job to at least have some idea of which one(s) you want to be improved.

Once you have figured out the area(s) you want to be improved, the next step is deciding on how to actually improve those areas. Options include but are not limited to:

- Reading about how to improve those areas through articles or books
- Running tests and seeing what performs better
- Hiring someone with expertise in that area and getting them to audit/improve your work

There are some tools like Google Lighthouse which can tell you an estimated rating of some of the factors of your website like page load speed and certain parts of accessibility but there is no one tool that can tell you how to optimize for every different things you could optimize for. Especially for something like optimizing for making money, there's no way a single tool (or person probably) can tell you the optimal way to do that.

There's also a possibility of hiring someone with more experience and skills in website/product design and asking them to provide insight into any areas that they think could be improved, basically outsourcing the "figure it out" portion. However, depending on their skillset, they may focus on certain areas and completely miss others. It's ultimately your job as the product owner to be responsible for improving all important areas of your product.